# Помогите сформировать SQL запрос

Tags: php, sql, drupal

Добрый день.
У меня на сайте нужно вывести товары, но проблема в том, что вся информация разбросана по разным таблицам БД. Если большинство информации я смог связать по ID товара, то со ссылками какая-то беда. Сайт на DRUPAL 6.
Есть некая таблица url_alias, в ней такие столбцы: pid, src, dst, language
Мне нужно выдернуть адрес по такому условию - записи у которых src = /node/740, где 740 - ID товара.
У меня есть массив из ID товаров

```
$pages_id= = array(840, 1411, 1390, 736, 898, 1578, 1337, 1381, 1581, 1563);
```

На данный момент у меня такой запрос:

```
$nodes = db_query("SELECT n.title, p.field_prod_price_value, p.field_sred_ocen_value, p.field_kol_gol_value FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {content_type_prod} p ON n.nid = p.nid WHERE n.nid IN (" . implode(",", $pages_id) . ")");
```

Мне необходимо добавить выборку поля dst чтобы поле `src = /node/ IN (" . implode(",", $pages_id) . ")` Не пойму как это сделать...

UPD:

Вот такой запрос выводит как нужно

```
$nodes = db_query("SELECT n.title, p.field_prod_price_value, p.field_sred_ocen_value, p.field_kol_gol_value, h.dst FROM ({node} n INNER JOIN {content_type_prod} p ON n.nid = p.nid)  INNER JOIN {url_alias} h ON h.src='node/840' WHERE n.nid IN (" . implode(",", $pages_id) . ")");
```

Как вместо `h.src='node/840'` поставить перебор массива `$pages_id` ? Вернее вместо 840 чтобы добавлялся перебор массива?

Comment: как таблица url_alias связывается с остальными?

Comment: Кривой запрос. Нужно или переделать эту часть ON h.src='node/840', или в цикле перебирать ваш массив $pages_id и отправлять столько запросов, сколько элементов в массиве (костыль).

Answer (score 0):

> Мне нужно выдернуть адрес по такому условию - записи у которых src = /node/740, где 740 - ID товара. У меня есть массив из ID товаров

Ну в качестве временного (и заведомо плохого, ибо фуллскан) решения можно предложить такой фортель:

```
WHERE /* или ON */ REPLACE(t1.src, '/node/', '') IN ( . implode(",", $pages_id) . )
```

Получше будет, если сделать наоборот, и к IDам добавить путь:

```
WHERE /* или ON */ t1.src IN ( . "/node/" . implode(",/node/", $pages_id) . )
```